# Can Nginx get the client requesting IP address or URL?

Tags: ip-address, nginx

In the config file of Nginx there's:

`proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`

Just wondering if there is any way you can figure out if the request is accessed from a request URL: `example.com` or the hosting IP: `168.123.123.1`